# Springboot - @Autowired null em arquivo de configuração

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Estou iniciando um projeto com springboot e preciso acessar algumas propriedades do application.properties por causa dos profiles.

Mas quando eu injeto a classe de configuração, sempre vem nulo, já pesquisei bastante mas deve ter algum detalhe que eu não estou me atentando...

Vou colocar os trechos das classes abaixo

Application.properties:

```
server.ip=000.000.000.000
server.port=0000
```

Classe de configuração:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server")
public class AppProperties {

    private String ip;
    private Integer port;

... getters ans setters
```

Classe onde preciso utilizar os valores:

```
@Component
public class Teste {

    @Autowired
    private AppProperties properties;

...

    socket = new Socket(properties.getIp(), properties.getPort());
```

Na ultima linha, a variável properties está nula.

Eu já debuguei e quando inicia a aplicação os valores são populados corretamente na classe AppProperties.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 0):

No `AppProperties` você deveria estar utilizando `@Configuration` ao invés de `@Component`. Sua configuração de prefixo está certa, acredito que o problema seja apenas a annotation incorreta.

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta. Já havia tentado com ambas as anotações. Quando eu inicio a aplicação e debugo essas variáveis elas estão com os valores corretos. Me parece que ao utilizar a injeção de dependência esses valores estão sendo perdidos.

Answer (score 0):

Em certo momento eu instanciava a classe Teste com `new Teste()`. Era aí que estava o problema.
Fiz injeção de dependência da classe `Teste` na classe de serviço onde eu vou precisar utiliza-la e tudo funcionou corretamente.